# Doesn't catch redirect in shouldOverrideUrlLoading

Tags: android, webview

Edit:
I found out that the web site is a single page website and that's probably the reason I didn't catch the change of the url so now my question is: Can I know the url changed on a single page website?

I have a webView which load a web site.
shouldOverrideUrlLoading called only once, on the first load of the page but not when it redirected inside the web.

This is the code of the webClient I use:

```
private class WebViewClientServiceGuide extends MyWebViewClient {
private WebView wv;

public WebViewClientServiceGuide(WebView _wv) {
    wv = _wv;
    Log.d(TAG, "WebViewClientServiceGuide.ctor");
}

public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
    Log.d(TAG, "WebViewClientServiceGuide - onLoadResource: " + url);
    super.onLoadResource(view, url);
}

@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    //Add history to history manager if needed
    Log.d(TAG, "WebViewClientServiceGuide - onPageFinished");
    super.onPageFinished(view,url);
}

@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
    Log.d(TAG, "WebViewClientServiceGuide - shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request)");
    return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request);
}

@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    Log.d(TAG, "WebViewClientServiceGuide - shouldOverrideUrlLoading");
    return false;
}
}
```

Lets say I visited these pages: page1, page2, page3 but catches only page1 on shouldOverrideUrlLoading. But when I examined the history of the webView (copyBackForwardList) I saw all the list (page1, page2, page3).

Why does it happens? (I tried to use other website and catches there all the pages - I know the web site developer should fix it but I want to know why the history stack is different than the urls I catch on shouldOverrideUrlLoading )

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:
I overrode a method of WebViewClient called doUpdateVisitedHistory which gets a url, even on single page website